# For loop for HTMLCollection elements

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to set get id of all elements in an `HTMLCollectionOf`. I wrote the following code:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("events");
console.log(list[0].id);
for (key in list) {
    console.log(key.id);
}
```

But I got the following output in console:

```
event1
undefined
```

which is not what I expected. Why is the second console output `undefined` but the first console output is `event1`?

Comment: **Word of caution**: Whatever construct you choose, please beaware of the fact that `getElementsByClassName` gives a live collection of nodes having that CSS class. So that collection might change if you play with `class` attribue of node being iterated within the loop. In that case, most of the constructs will go for a toss except `Array.from(....).forEach`. `Array.from` does object cloning and creates a separate object which is then iterated.

Answer (score 1354, accepted):

In response to the original question, you are using `for/in` incorrectly.  In your code, `key` is the index.  So, to get the value from the pseudo-array, you'd have to do `list[key]` and to get the id, you'd do `list[key].id`.  But, you should not be doing this with `for/in` in the first place.

**Summary (added in Dec 2018)**

Do not ever use `for/in` to iterate a nodeList or an HTMLCollection.  The reasons to avoid it are described below.

All recent versions of modern browsers (Safari, Firefox, Chrome, Edge) all support `for/of` iteration on DOM lists such `nodeList` or `HTMLCollection`.

Here's an example:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("events");
for (let item of list) {
    console.log(item.id);
}
```

To include older browsers (including things like IE), this will work everywhere:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("events");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    console.log(list[i].id); //second console output
}
```

---

**Explanation For Why You Should Not Use `for/in`**

`for/in` is meant for iterating the properties of an object.  That means it will return all iterable properties of an object.  While it may appear to work for an array (returning array elements or pseudo-array elements), it can also return other properties of the object that are not what you are expecting from the array-like elements.  And, guess what, an `HTMLCollection` or `nodeList` object can both have other properties that will be returned with a `for/in` iteration.  I just tried this in Chrome and iterating it the way you were iterating it will retrieve the items in the list (indexes 0, 1, 2, etc...), but also will retrieve the `length` and `item` properties.  The `for/in` iteration simply won't work for an HTMLCollection.

---

See http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/FzZ2H/ for why you can't iterate an HTMLCollection with `for/in`.

In Firefox, your `for/in` iteration would return these items (all the iterable properties of the object):

```
0
1
2
item
namedItem
@@iterator
length
```

Hopefully, now you can see why you want to use `for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)` instead so you just get `0`, `1` and `2` in your iteration.

---

**Evolution of Browser Support for NodeList and HTMLCollection iteration**

Following below is an evolution of how browsers have evolved through the time period 2015-2018 giving you additional ways to iterate.  None of these are now needed in modern browsers since you can use the options described above.

**Update for ES6 in 2015**

Added to ES6 is `Array.from()` that will convert an array-like structure to an actual array.  That allows one to enumerate a list directly like this:

```
"use strict";

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("events")).forEach(function(item) {
   console.log(item.id);
});
```

Working demo (in Firefox, Chrome, and Edge as of April 2016): https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/8ar4xn2s/

---

**Update for ES6 in 2016**

You can now use the ES6 for/of construct with a `NodeList` and an `HTMLCollection` by just adding this to your code:

```
NodeList.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator];
HTMLCollection.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator];
```

Then, you can do:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("events");
for (var item of list) {
    console.log(item.id);
}
```

This works in the current version of Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.  This works because it attaches the Array iterator to both the NodeList and HTMLCollection prototypes so that when for/of iterates them, it uses the Array iterator to iterate them.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/joy06u4e/.

---

**Second Update for ES6 in Dec 2016**

As of Dec 2016, `Symbol.iterator` support has been built-in to Chrome v54 and Firefox v50 so the code below works by itself.  It is not yet built-in for Edge.

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("events");
for (let item of list) {
    console.log(item.id);
}
```

Working demo (in Chrome and Firefox): http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3ddpz8sp/

**Third Update for ES6 in Dec 2017**

As of Dec. 2017, this capability works in Edge 41.16299.15.0 for a `nodeList` as in `document.querySelectorAll()`, but not an `HTMLCollection` as in `document.getElementsByClassName()` so you have to manually assign the iterator to use it in Edge for an `HTMLCollection`.  It is a total mystery why they'd fix one collection type, but not the other.  But, you can at least use the result of `document.querySelectorAll()` with ES6 `for/of` syntax in current versions of Edge now.

I've also updated the above jsFiddle so it tests both `HTMLCollection` and `nodeList` separately and captures the output in the jsFiddle itself.

**Fourth Update for ES6 in Mar 2018**

Per mesqueeeb, `Symbol.iterator` support has been built-in to Safari too, so you can use `for (let item of list)` for either `document.getElementsByClassName()` or `document.querySelectorAll()`.

**Fifth Update for ES6 in Apr 2018**

Apparently, support for iterating an `HTMLCollection` with `for/of` will be coming to Edge 18 in Fall 2018.

**Sixth Update for ES6 in Nov 2018**

I can confirm that with Microsoft Edge v18 (that is included in the Fall 2018 Windows Update), you can now iterate both an HTMLCollection and a NodeList with for/of in Edge.

So, now all modern browsers contain native support for `for/of` iteration of both the HTMLCollection and NodeList objects.

Comment: Thank you for the great updates you have been doing. Just out of interest, do you know if they are going to add that HTMLCollection should have Symbol.iterator into the spec? 
I know all the browsers are doing it, but as far as I know, the spec has no mention of it, and the Typescript definitions are built from spec, not implementations.

Comment: @WORMSS - I don't know.  But, if I were to guess, this note in the [LivingStandard document](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#old-style-collections): **HTMLCollection is a historical artifact we cannot rid the web of. While developers are of course welcome to keep using it, new API standard designers ought not to use it (use sequence<T> in IDL instead)** sounds like it's not likely to get enhanced any more as they don't want to encourage you to use the live collections APIs any more - probably because it's very easy to create bugs if you are iterating a live collection while modifying the DOM.

Comment: to be able to use "for (let item of list)" in typescript, I had to add "dom.iterable" to tsconfig.json, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60342425/379279

Comment: Summary (Dec 2018) advice conflicts with latest update (sixth, Nov 2018). Should we or shouldn't we use for/of for HTMLCollection and NodeList?

Comment: @AhmedTawfik - Where's the conflict?  Please explain more specifically. It looks to me like both the summary and the sixth update say you can use `for/of` with DOM collections in all modern browsers as of 2018.  And, FYI 5 years have passed since this was edited so it would be a really old (non-modern) browser that doesn't include support for `for/of` with DOM collections.

Comment: Sorry I didn't distinguish between for/in and for/of. My bad.

Comment: With `console.log(list)` I get `HTMLCollection [] (0)`. With `for..of` I get nothing, with `for..in` I get output which is not what I want as you wrote. I am hopeless as I tried *all* from here, I use recent Chromium on Macos.

Comment: @Timo - Try `console.log(Array.from(list))` and  `console.log(Array.from(list).length)` and see what you get.  It seems to me that it's possible your list is just empty.

Comment: correct, empty, have a look at the [github code](https://github.com/tik9/fun/blob/400026cafb1e44ff13a77d5e3219b10d4525551a/public/js/cloud.js#L58) please. The buttons I need are created from js, maybe that is the cause?

Comment: @Timo - I think it's pretty clear now that your issue does not have anything to do with THIS question so we shouldn't continue to discuss it here.  Please write your own question and show all the relevant details and ask a clear question.

Comment: to understand my problem: i create dynamically buttons in a js loop and the buttons are not available after creation in the same script. The cause could be async. I will post a question.

Answer (score 95):

You can't use `for`/`in` on `NodeList`s or `HTMLCollection`s. However, you can use some `Array.prototype` methods, as long as you `.call()` them and pass in the `NodeList` or `HTMLCollection` as `this`.

So consider the following as an alternative to [jfriend00's `for` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22754453/414220):

```
var list= document.getElementsByClassName("events");
[].forEach.call(list, function(el) {
    console.log(el.id);
});
```

There's a good [article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Why_can't_I_use_forEach_or_map_on_a_NodeList.3F) that covers this technique. Note their warning about browser compatibility though:

> [...] passing a host object (like a `NodeList`) as
>   `this` to a native method (such as `forEach`) is not guaranteed to work in
>   all browsers and is known to fail in some.

So while this approach is convenient, a `for` loop may be the most browser-compatible solution.

**Update (Aug 30, 2014):** Eventually you'll be able to use [ES6 `for`/`of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)!

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("events");
for (const el of list)
  console.log(el.id);
```

It's already supported in recent versions of Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Very nice! I used this technique to get the values of selected options from a `<select multiple>`. Example: `[].map.call(multiSelect.selectedOptions, function(option) { return option.value; })`

Comment: I was looking for an ES2015 solution to this, so thanks for confirming that `for ... of` works.

Answer (score 88):

In ES6, you could do something like `[...collection]`, or `Array.from(collection)`,

```
let someCollection = document.querySelectorAll(someSelector)
[...someCollection].forEach(someFn) 
//or
Array.from(collection).forEach(someFn)
```

Eg:-

```
    navDoms = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-container');
    Array.from(navDoms).forEach(function(navDom){
     //implement function operations
    });
```

Comment: @DanielM guess what I have done is, shallow clone an array-like structure

Comment: I see, thanks -- now I have found the documentation I was looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: I always use this, much easier to the eyes than Array.from, I just wonder if it has considerable performance or memory drawbacks. For example if I need to iterate a table row's cells I use a `[...row.cells].forEach` instead of doing a `row.querySelectorAll('td')`

Answer (score 17):

you can add this two lines:

```
HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
```

*HTMLCollection* is return by *getElementsByClassName* and *getElementsByTagName*

*NodeList* is return by *querySelectorAll*

Like this you can do a forEach:

```
var selections = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');

/* alternative :
var selections = document.querySelectorAll('.myClass');
*/

selections.forEach(function(element, i){
//do your stuffs
});
```

Comment: This answer seems so effective. What is the catch?

Comment: The catch is that this solution doesn't work on IE11 !
Good solution though.

Comment: Note that [`NodeList` already has `forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Comment: I am curious about browsers support of this. Looks awesome.

Answer (score 13):

Alternative to `Array.from` is to use `Array.prototype.forEach.call`

**forEach:**
`Array.prototype.forEach.call(htmlCollection, i => { console.log(i) });`

**map:** `Array.prototype.map.call(htmlCollection, i => { console.log(i) });`

Answer (score 10):

There's no reason to use es6 features to escape `for` looping if you're on IE9 or above.

In ES5, there are two good options. First, you can "borrow" `Array`'s `forEach` as [evan mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25587133/1028230).

But even better...

#### Use `Object.keys()`, which *does* have `forEach` and filters to "own properties" automatically.

That is, [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Browser_compatibility) is essentially equivalent to doing a `for... in` with a `HasOwnProperty`, but is much smoother.

```
var eventNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("events");
Object.keys(eventNodes).forEach(function (key) {
    console.log(eventNodes[key].id);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a problem using forEach in **IE 11** and also **Firefox 49**

I have found a workaround like this

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("events")).forEach(function (key) {
        console.log(key.id);
    }
```

Comment: Great solution for IE11! Used to be a [common technique](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/4z42z0/var_args_arrayprototypeslicecallarguments_the/)...

Answer (score 5):

As of March 2016, in Chrome 49.0, `for...of` works for `HTMLCollection`:

```
this.headers = this.getElementsByTagName("header");

for (var header of this.headers) {
    console.log(header); 
}
```

See [here the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

But it only works if you apply the following workaround **before** using the `for...of`:

```
HTMLCollection.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator];
```

The same is necessary for using `for...of` with `NodeList`:

```
NamedNodeMap.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator];
```

I believe/hope `for...of` will soon work without the above workaround. The open issue is here:

> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=401699

**Update:** See Expenzor's comment below: *This has been fixed as of April 2016. You don't need to add HTMLCollection.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator]; to iterate over an HTMLCollection with for...of*

Comment: This has been fixed as of April 2016. You don't need to add `HTMLCollection.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator];` to iterate over an `HTMLCollection` with `for...of`.

Answer (score 4):

Easy workaround that I always use

```
let list = document.getElementsByClassName("events");
let listArr = Array.from(list)
```

After this you can run any desired Array methods on the selection

```
listArr.map(item => console.log(item.id))
listArr.forEach(item => console.log(item.id))
listArr.reverse()
```

Answer (score 3):

On Edge

```
if(!NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
  NodeList.prototype.forEach = function(fn, scope) {
    for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
      fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use oldder varsions of ES, (ES5 for example), you can use `as any`:

```
for (let element of elementsToIterate as any) {
      console.log(element);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this:

```
 let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
 for(let index in  elements) {
   if(index <= elements.length) {
        console.log(elements[index]);
  }
}
```

```js
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
for (let index in elements) {
  if (index <= elements.length) {
    console.log(elements[index]);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="classname"> element 1 </div>
<div class="classname"> element 2 </div>
<div class="classname"> element 3 </div>
```

or

```
 let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
 for(let ele of  elements) {
        console.log(ele);
}
```

```js
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
for (let ele of elements) {
  console.log(ele);
}
```

```html
<div class="classname"> element 1 </div>
<div class="classname"> element 2 </div>
<div class="classname"> element 3 </div>
<div class="classname"> element 4 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete all options from `datalist`:

```
function removeOptions(datalist_id) {
    const selectElement = document.getElementById(datalist_id);
    Array.from(selectElement.children).forEach(el=> el.remove());
}
```

Then call this:

```
removeOptions("your_datalist_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to change it to

```
var list= document.getElementsByClassName("events");
console.log(list[0].id); //first console output
for (key in list){
    console.log(list[key].id); //second console output
}
```

Comment: FYI, see my answer for why this won't work properly.  The `for (key in list)` will return several properties of the `HTMLCollection` that are not meant to be items in the collection.