# Conflict between Array.prototype and a chain select box plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

[Chained select box](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/53/) fiddle

[Chained select box and an Array.prototype function](http://jsfiddle.net/uzeyehjv/) fiddle

I had a chained select box and an `Array.prototype` function to combine two arrays into an associated array.They are for different use and unrelated. But when they are put together in the script, it gives me `undefined is not a function` pointing to this part `this.forEach` as the source of error. I ended up replacing the `Array.prototype` function with this one ([Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uzeyehjv/1/)):

```
function associate(keys, values){
    return keys.reduce(function (previous, key, index) {
        previous[key] = values[index];
        return previous
    }, {})
}
```

I'm just curious why there is a conflict between the chained select box and the `Array.prototype` function?

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var data = [
  {
    "bigcat": "Sport",
    "cat": "mainstream",
    "choice": "football"
  },
  {
    "bigcat": "Sport",
    "cat": "mainstream",
    "choice": "basketball"
  },
  {
    "bigcat": "Sport",
    "cat": "niche",
    "choice": "MMA"
  },
  {
    "bigcat": "Sport",
    "cat": "niche",
    "choice": "wrestling"
  }
]

var $select = $('select');var $option="";

$.each(data, function (index, i) {

  $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", i.choice).text(i.bigcat + "@" +( i.cat || "") +"@" +  i.choice);

  $select.append($option); 
});


$select.dynamicDropdown({"delimiter":"@"});

});

Array.prototype.associate = function (keys) {
  var result = {};

  this.forEach(function (el, i) {
    result[keys[i]] = el;
  });

  return result;
};

var animals = ['Cow', 'Pig', 'Dog', 'Cat'];
var sounds = ['Moo', 'Oink', 'Woof', 'Miao'];
console.dir(sounds.associate(animals));
```

Dynamic Drop down box Script

```
(function($) {
  $.dynamicDropdown = {
    /**
     * Escape quotation marks and slashes
     * @param {String} String to format
     * @return {String}
     */
    escapeQuotes : function(str) {
      return str.replace(/([""\\])/g, "\\$1");
    },

    /**
     * Build a <select> box from options
     * @param {Array} Options
     * @return {jQuery}
     */
    buildSelectDropdown : function(options) {
      var select = $(document.createElement("select"));
      var option = null;

      // Add options
      for (var i in options) {

        option = $(document.createElement("option"))
          .val($.isArray(options[i]) ? i : options[i])
          .html(i)
          .appendTo(select);
      }

      return select;
    }
  };

  $.fn.dynamicDropdown = function(options) {
    var settings = {
      "delimiter" : " ?",
      "className" : "dynamic-dropdown"
    };

    $.extend(settings, options);

    return $(this).each(function() {
      /**
       * Main dropdown (this)
       * @type jQuery
       */
      var mainDropdown = $(this);

      /**
       * Position of initial value of main dropdown
       * @type Array
       */
      var initialPosition = [];

      /**
       * Main array of all elements
       * @type Array
       */
      var data = [];

      /**
       * Array of all <select> boxes
       * @type Array
       */
      var selectElements = [];

      /**
       * Flag denoting whether the dropdown has been initialized
       * @type Boolean
       */
      var isInitialized = false;

      /**
       * Prepare a dropdown for use as a dynamic dropdown
       * @param {jQuery|string} Dropdown
       * @param {jQuery|HTMLElement} Sibling
       * @param {Number} Level
       * @param {Number} Position in the main array
       * @return {jQuery}
       */
      var prepareDropdown = function(dropdown, sibling, level, position) {
        return $(dropdown)
          .addClass(settings.className)
          .data("level", level)
          .data("position", position)
          .insertAfter(sibling)
          .each(buildDynamicDropdown)
          .change(buildDynamicDropdown);
      };

      /**
       * Initialize the dynamic dropdown <select> boxes
       * @return {jQuery}
       */
      var buildDynamicDropdown = function() {
        var level = $(this).data("level") + 1;
        var position = "";

        // Get the position in the main data array
        if (!isInitialized) {
          for (var i = 0; i < level; i++) {
            position += "[\"" + initialPosition[i] + "\"]";
          }
        } else {
          position = $(this).data("position") + "[\"" + $.dynamicDropdown.escapeQuotes($(this).val()) + "\"]";

          // Remove old <select> boxes
          for (var i = selectElements.length; i > level; i--) {
            selectElements.pop().remove();
          }
        }

        var selectionOptions = eval("data" + position);

        if ($.isArray(selectionOptions)) {
          // Build the next dropdown
          selectElements.push($.dynamicDropdown.buildSelectDropdown(selectionOptions));

          if (!isInitialized) {
            $(this).val(initialPosition[level - 1]);
          }

          prepareDropdown(selectElements[selectElements.length - 1], this, level, position);
        } else if (!isInitialized) {
          // Set the final value
          $("option:contains('" + initialPosition[level - 1] + "')", selectElements[selectElements.length - 1]).attr("selected", "selected");
          isInitialized = true;
        } else {
          // Set the value
          mainDropdown.val($(this).val());
        }

        return $(this);
      };

      // Build the dynamic dropdown data
      mainDropdown.children().each(function() {
        var parts = $(this).html().split(settings.delimiter);
        var name = "data";
        var value = null;

        // Set the initial position
        if ($(this).is(":selected")) {
          initialPosition = parts;
        }

        // Build the position of the current item
        for (var i in parts) {
if(typeof parts[i] != "string") continue;
          name += "[\"" + $.dynamicDropdown.escapeQuotes(parts[i]) + "\"]";
          value = eval(name);
          if (!value) {
            // Set the level to have an empty array to be filled
            eval(name + " = [];");
          } else if (!$.isArray(value)) {
            // Add data to the array
            eval(name + " = [" + eval(name) + "];");
          }
        }

        // Set the final index to have the value
        eval(name + " = \"" + $(this).val() + "\";");
      });

      // Build the dynamic dropdown
      selectElements[0] = $.dynamicDropdown.buildSelectDropdown(data);
      prepareDropdown(selectElements[0], this, 0, "");
    }).hide();
  };
})(jQuery);
```

[Github version:](https://gist.github.com/jayalfredprufrock/1356298)

```
(function($) 
{

    $.fn.dynamicDropdown = function(options) {

        var settings = {
            "delimiter" : " » ",
            "className" : "",
            "levels"    : [ 
                {'markup':"{dd}",'class':false,'id':false,'disabled':false},
                {'markup':"{dd}"}
            ]
        };

        $.extend(settings, options);

        return $(this).each(function() {

            //the original dropdown element
            var mainDropdown = $(this);

            var defaultSelection = false;


            var levels = {};

            //insert dropdown into markup, and finally place it in the DOM, attaching events, etc.
            var insertSelectDropdown = function(dd, level, sibling, position){

                var markup = settings.levels[level] && settings.levels[level].markup ? settings.levels[level].markup : '{dd}';

                //to support markup both placing the dropdown within a container and without a container, 
                //its necessary to use a little silly dom magic
                var container = $('<div>'+settings.levels[level].markup.replace('{dd}',$('<div></div>').append(dd.addClass('ddlevel-'+level)).html())+'</div>').children()['insert'+position](sibling);

                var select = container.parent().find('select.ddlevel-'+level).removeClass('ddlevel-'+level);

                if (settings.levels[level]['class']){

                    select.addClass(settings.levels[level]['class']);
                }

                if (settings.levels[level].id){

                    select.attr('id',settings.levels[level].id);
                }

                if (settings.levels[level].disabled){

                    select.prop('disabled','disabled');
                }


                return select.data('level',level).data('container',container).data('levels',dd.data('levels')).change(updateDropdowns);
            }

            //produce markup for select element
            var buildSelectDropdown = function(options, selected) {

                var select = $('<select></select>').data('levels',options);

                // Add options
                $.each(options,function(index,value){

                    var option = $('<option></option>').html(index);

                    if (typeof(value) != 'object'){

                        option.val(value);
                    }

                    if (selected && index == selected){

                        option.attr('selected','selected');
                    }

                    select.append(option);

                });

                return select;
            };


            //the event function that runs each time a select input value changes
            var updateDropdowns = function(){

                var current = $(this).children(':selected').html();

                var options = $(this).data('levels')[current];

                //a non-object means this is the end of the line, set the value
                if (typeof(options) != 'object'){

                    mainDropdown.val($(this).val());
                }
                else {
                    //remove any dds after the one that just changed
                    var dd = $(this);
                    while (dd.data('next')){

                        dd = dd.data('next');

                        dd.data('container').detach();
                    }

                    var level = $(this).data('level') + 1;

                    //add new dds
                    $(this).data('next',insertSelectDropdown(buildSelectDropdown(options, defaultSelection[level]), level, $(this).data('container').last(), 'After').change());
                }

            };

            //build levels from initial dropdown
            mainDropdown.children().each(function() {

                var options = $(this).html().split(settings.delimiter); 

                if ($(this).is(":selected")){

                    defaultSelection = options;
                }       

                var level = levels;

                for (var i=0; i < options.length; i++) {

                    if (!level[options[i]]){

                        //either an option is an object pointing to other objects/values,
                        //or some other type value, indicating that the user has made a selection
                        level[options[i]] = ((i+1)==options.length) ? $(this).val() : {};
                    }

                    level = level[options[i]];
                }

            });

            //if no default selection, use first value
            if (!defaultSelection){

                defaultSelection = mainDropdown.children().first().html().split(settings.delimiter);
            }

            insertSelectDropdown(buildSelectDropdown(levels,defaultSelection[0]), 0, mainDropdown, 'Before').change();


        //hide initial dropdown
        }).hide();
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: it uses an unfiltered for-in loop to iterate an Array. in other words, it's poorly written if it's supposed to be a tool others use.

Comment: use Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,"associate", function (keys) {... to fix it.

Comment: related, if not duplicate of: [How to define method in javascript on Array.prototype and Object.prototype so that it doesn't appear in for in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused because the `dynamicDropdown` code iterates over an array with this type of syntax:

```
for (prop in array)
```

which includes all iterable properties of the array, not just array elements.  In your case, that will include the `associate` method that you added to the array because it is iterable and that will cause a problem.

For a reference on iterating arrays, see [Right and Wrong Ways to Iterate an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/for-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements/22754453#22754453).

This is a classic example for why arrays should never be iterated with the `for (prop in array)` syntax, but rather this

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
```

or this:

```
array.forEach()
```

or the more modern:

```
for (item of array)
```

and it's also a classic example of the risk you take when you add things directly to the `Array.prototype` as you've done.

---

You can work-around it as you have done by not extending the prototype of the `Array` object at all (the option you've already discovered).  Or, you could make your new method be non-iterable by using `Object.defineProperty()` rather than direct assignment to the prototype (as long as you're OK with only IE9+ support) so the bad code in the `dynamicDropdown` library won't see your new method in its array iteration.

You could use `Object.defineProperty()` like this to make the method be non-iterable:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "associate", {
    writable: false,
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    value: function(keys) {
        var result = {};

        this.forEach(function (el, i) {
          result[keys[i]] = el;
        });

        return result;
    }
});
```

Comment: jfriend00, thank you for your detailed explanation. I have updated the post to show the old code and the github version for the select box plugin. My fiddle example is using the old one

Comment: @RedGiant - Is there a question you have relative to these two versions of the select box plugin?  I've explained the issue with the version in the jsFiddle that was giving you the problem.  The Github version works quite differently, but I didn't test it to see if it has this issue too.