# Javascript for each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm trying to write this:

```
$('.circle_div').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            thisWidth = $this.width();
        $this.css('height', thisWidth + 'px');
    });
```

in javascript like this:

```
var circle_div = document.getElementsByClassName('circle_div');
for (el in circle_div){
    var thisWidth = el.style.width;
    el.style.height = thisWidth + "px";
}
```

I also tried [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and `for each`, and a regular for loop incrementing var i. The jquery function works but the javascript doesn't. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert the `NodeList` object that returns `getElementsByCLassName` to a regular array, you can use the `Array.prototype.forEach` method on it:

```
// Get the divs, and convert the NodeList to a regular array.
var circle_div = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('circle_div'), 0);

circle_div.forEach(function (el) {
    el.style.height = el.clientWidth + "px";
});
```

This way looks more similar to your jquery code.

**Check the fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7ew39phu/

---

Edit: I realize I should have used `clientWidth`, instead of `style.width`. The reason is that `style` properties seem to be only available if they were set using JavaScript, not if they were set using an css sylesheet.

Anyway, I fixed the code.

Comment: this issue seems inconclusive. whenever i write this in javascript, i'm unable to change the height of my circle_div elements but when i write in jquery, it works perfectly.

Comment: @Zack Fixed, please check the change and the fiddle!

Answer (score 5):

Eeeck. Never use `for/in` to iterate elements of an array or array-like object (doing so will include other iterable properties in addition to just the array elements).

Plus `el` in your loop is the index, not the value. You have to use `circle_div[index]` to get the element from the `nodeList`. But, you MUST switch to a traditional for loop, not `for/in`.

```
var circle_div = document.getElementsByClassName('circle_div');
for (var i = 0; i < circle_div.length; i++) {
    var item = circle_div[i];
    item.style.height = item.style.width;
}
```

You also have to remove the `+ "px"` because the units are already there in plain javascript.

For more details on using `for` loop with `document.getElementsByClassName()` (including ES6 info), see this other answer: [For loop for HTMLCollection elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/for-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements/22754453#22754453).

Comment: gotcha! i read through documentation and just thought i'd try them all.

Comment: @Zack - do you realize that if you get an answer that solves your question, then you should select the best answer and click the green check mark to the left of that answer.  That both rewards the person that provided the answer and earns you some reputation points for following the correct procedure.

Comment: apologies, i actually moved on with my original jquery for a couple days because the style property wasn't accessible _(see chris-l's explanation above)_

Answer (score 0):

```
var circle_div = document.getElementsByClassName('circle_div');
for (var i=0,l=circle_div.length; i<l; i++){
    circle_div[i].style.height = circle_div[i].style.width;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, that's what i wrote but it's something else. could it be getElementsByClassName?