# Adding a child element to all divs of the same class

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to add a child span to all div's with the same class.

I can achieve this to a individual element by targeting its Id

**HTML**

```
<div id="h1" class="header">Hello </div>
<hr>
<div id="h2" class="header">what about this one </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var header = document.getElementById('h1');

var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
header.appendChild(newSpan);
newSpan.innerHTML = "i'm here";
```

However when I change it to

```
var header = document.getElementsByClassName('header');
```

It fails to work.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/garyvoss/fef55j76/)

Comment: <div id="h1" class = "header">Hello </div>
<div id="h2" class ="header">what about this one </div> you forget  '='  sign

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do that you need to iterate over them, since **[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** returns an array like html element collection. You can use `for` loop

```js
var headers = document.getElementsByClassName('header');

for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
  var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
  newSpan.innerHTML = "i'm here";
  headers[i].appendChild(newSpan);
}
```

```html
<div id="h1" class="header">Hello</div>
<hr>
<div id="h2" class="header">what about this one</div>
```

or you can use **[`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** with **[`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)** to iterate over it

```js
var headers = document.getElementsByClassName('header');

[].forEach.call(headers,function(ele) {
  var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
  newSpan.innerHTML = "i'm here";
  ele.appendChild(newSpan);
})
```

```html
<div id="h1" class="header">Hello</div>
<hr>
<div id="h2" class="header">what about this one</div>
```

For more about iteration check :- [For loop for HTMLCollection elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/foreach-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements)

Comment: @GaryVoss : glad to help

Comment: Fun fact: `[].forEach.call()` and `for in` are much slower than `[].slice.call().forEach()`: http://jsperf.com/oneanother

Answer (score 0):

The javascript document.getElementById will return only one Id, but document.getElementByClassName will return a collection of array-like objects and it should be used here.

I have updated your js code to :

```
var header = document.getElementsByClassName('header');
//console.log(header);

for(var i=0;i<header.length;i++){
    var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
    header[i].appendChild(newSpan);
    newSpan.innerHTML = "i'm here";
}
```

and HTML code to :

```
<div id="h1" class="header">Hello </div>
<hr>  
<div id="h2" class="header">what about this one </div>
```

HTML code had some slight mistake of *class"header"* instead *class="header"*

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fef55j76/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider inserting the text as CSS generated content:

```css
.header::after {
  content: "i'm here";
}
```

```html
<div id="h1" class="header">Hello </div>
<hr />
<div id="h2" class="header">what about this one </div>
```