# What's the difference between getElementById and getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

I know maybe is not the right way of using the `getElementsByClassName`. For example the code below doesn't work as it is ¿why?, but when change `getElementsByClassName("demo")` for `getElementById("demo2")` does work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p class="demo" id="demo2">anything</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split(" ");
document.getElementsByNameClass("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because `getElementsByNameClass` (it actually should be `getElementsByClassName`) returns a collection and `getElementById` returns one element. The collection doesn't have `innerHTML` property and setting it has no effect.

Comment: I'm surprised `getElementsByNameClass` does anything.

Comment: The OP had it spelled correctly in 75% of the attempts in the question. The one misspelled occurrence is certainly a typo.

Comment: @Vohuman: Please write your answers in the _answer section_. You can find it down below.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sarcasm? Many questions on SO are either duplicates or super-simple problems. This is why I usually don't post answers. But you are right, comments can overshadow answers. I'll consider this.

Comment: @Vohuman: Why would it be sarcasm? Answers do not belong in the comments section, ever. They cannot be downvoted, they do not enter review queues, and they cannot be edited. The comments section is for _comments_. The answer section is for your answers. And if you encounter a duplicate or a super-simple problem, you should not be encouraging it by answering it anyway. Stack Overflow was founded on the express principle of providing quality, peer-reviewed Q&A; it is _not_ a message board or chatroom! (Although we do have some of those if you want to do personal help outside of the Q&A model).

Comment: (I realise the irony of saying you shouldn't answer dupes. I didn't know this was a dupe when I answered it :P The difference is that you seem to be doing so deliberately.)

Answer (score 0):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a collection (an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which is "an array-like object"), because there may be multiple elements with that class name. **A collection has no `innerHTML` property.** You would have to [iterate over each element in the collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22754453/560648) using a loop:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   elements[i].innerHTML = res;
}
```

By contrast, `getElementById` returns a single element, and it can do so because an IDs are unique.

<sup>(I'm assuming that `getElementsByNameClass` in your example is a typo.)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById()` is used to access the DOM elements using their `id` and `getElementsByClassName()` is used to access element(s) using their `class`.

Your code does not work because `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array-like object of all elements with given class. You need to access the first element of the array for your scenario

```html
    <html>
    <body>

    <p>Click the button.</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p class="demo" id="demo2">anything</p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var str = "How are you doing today?";
      var res = str.split(" ");
      document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0].innerHTML = res;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It's not an array.

Comment: Updated with correction. Its array-like object

Comment: Furthermore it seems to me that if the OP only wanted to do things with the first instance of the class (why the first? why not the second? third?) they'd have used an ID instead.

Comment: Agreed. But the solution to specific code snippet requires it to be the first member of the list (array-like object)

Comment: The code snippet was an "example". Taking its unmentioned specifics as requirements is unwise when giving a solution to a general question. Why not use a loop? That has the added advantage of not causing a nasty error message and breaking your script, when no matching elements are found.