# How can I set html of custom tag with jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery, jsp, tags, taglib, custom-tags

In my JSP file there is a custom tag `<table:page page="${page}"></table:page>` .

I want to update value of ${page} by ajax.

Now ajax **return** a successful value.

The returned value seems like `<div><ul><li></li></ul><div>`,

But I have an idea that how can I get this custom tag and set html to it ?

In tag file it is like this `<%@ attribute name="page" type="com.common.Page" required="true"%>`

I tried many ways, but it doesn`t work.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: you can change attribute's value using Jquery.

Comment: But I tried alert(document.getElementsByTagName('table:page').html()); It is undefined

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByTagName('table:page') will retrieve the HtmlCollection you desire.

Comment: But I tried alert(document.getElementsByTagName('table:page').innerHTML); It is undefined

Comment: Sorry for the late answer - it returns a HtmlCollection and you can iterate through it. (see here how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/foreach-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements)