# Working code brings error addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I use this code:

```
for (el in document.getElementsByClassName("close-sidenav"))
document.getElementsByClassName("close-sidenav")[el].addEventListener("click", closeSidenav);
```

and it works perfectly, it adds click event on elements, but Chrome keeps telling me this:
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[el].addEventListener is not a function(…)

How do I prevent Chrome from giving me an error on working code?

Comment: It's not really a running code if it throws an error, now is it? Anyway, my guess is that it's because you're doing `for...in` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [foreach loop for HTMLCollection elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/foreach-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an HTMLCollection object.

That object has numeric properties, but also has other properties that will be included in a for/in enumeration.

So, don't use for/in with the HTMLCollection returned by `document.getElementsByClassName()` because it will return other properties of that data structure that are not the elements you want.

Instead, use a regular `for` loop.

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("close-sidenav");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].addEventListener("click", closeSidenav);
}
```

See this other answer [For loop for HTMLCollection elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/foreach-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements/22754453#22754453) for many more details including cool ways to do this iteration in ES6 using `Array.from()` or ways to use `for/of` loops.

Comment: It worked! Thank a lot!
I've changed it to
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("close-sidenav").length; i++)
 document.getElementsByClassName("close-sidenav")[i].addEventListener("click", closeSidenav);

Comment: @Openup - That is inefficient because you're evaluating `document.getElementsByClassName("close-sidenav")` many times.  That's why I assign it to a local variable so it only has to be evaluated once.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that you are trying, you could use the following snippet to do the same job.

```
// Initially we grab once here the elements
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("close-sidenav"); 
if(elements){
    // We found elements with the specified class.
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
        // Then we attach here an event listener to them.
        elements[i].addEventListener("click", closeSidenav);
    }
}
```

In the above snippet, note that we have used a simple `for` structure and not a `for...in` structure. The latter does something different compared to the `for`. It loops through the keys of the object you have after the `in`.