# getElementsByClassName().forEach() function in JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, foreach

I am trying to get each element of HTML by Class name with JavaScript and then change its height and width according to the value in a `range` object `onchange`.

The browser is showing an error: `document.getElementsByClassName(...).forEach is not a function`

But I tried to structure it every way possible and still nothing.

This is how my first JavaScript code looked like:

```js
function updateInput(val) {
    document.getElementById('valueInput').innerHTML=val; /*This is just to show the value to the user*/
    document.getElementsByClassName('oneResult').forEach(functio‌​n changeWidth(element) { element.style.width = val + 'px'; } );
    document.getElementsByClassName('oneResult').forEach(functio‌​n changeWidth(element) { element.style.height = val + 'px'; } );
}
```

Then I tried this:

```js
function updateInput(val) {
    document.getElementById('valueInput').innerHTML=val;
    function oneResultWH(element) {
        element.style.width = val + 'px';
        element.style.height = val + 'px';
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName('oneResult').forEach(oneResultWH);
}
```

But still no luck.

This is how my PHP looks like:

```php
print '<div class="oneResult" style="background-image:url(Pictures/'.$img.'); height: 100px; width:100px; ">
<a id="word'. $x .'">'. $textConversion[$x] .'</a></div>';
```

Comment: You can learn more about HTML collections in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/for-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The browser is showing an error: document.getElementsByClassName(...).forEach is not a function

That's because `getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an array, it returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#htmlcollection). They don't have a `forEach` method (yet; it may at some point, or not).

You can use the one that arrays have like this:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("oneResult"), function(element) {
    // Use `element` here
});
```

Or on modern browsers (or with a polyfill) you can create an array from the collection:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("oneResult")).forEach(function(element) {
    // Use `element` here
});
```

Another option is to add `forEach` to `HTMLCollection`, which you can do like this on any vaguely-modern browser (even IE8, if you polyfill `Array.prototype.forEach` first):

```
if (typeof HTMLCollection !== "undefined" && HTMLCollection.prototype && !HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach) {
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLCollection.prototype, "forEach", {
        value: Array.prototype.forEach,
        configurable: true,
        writable: true
    });
}
```

Finally, note that while `HTMLCollection` doesn't have `forEach`, the `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll` does, though on some older browsers it may need to be polyfilled. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929157/foreach-on-queryselectorall-not-working-in-recent-microsoft-browsers/46929259#46929259) about polyfilling `NodeList` if necessary.

More:

- [*For-each over an array in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) (some answers there -- including mine -- have a section on "array-like" things, which includes `HTMLCollection`s)
- [*What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy* methods return?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. All this time I thought that `getElementsByClassName` creates an array..