# how to get and set div.class height

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Please suggest me any way to get and update the height of a HTML element in typescript.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('height').style.height = childHeight;
```

is not working. I get

> Property 'style' does not exist on type 'HtmlCollectionOf<Element>'

Answer (score 4):

One problem here might be that `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements with class `height`. To apply [`style` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) you need to have one element.

This code will apply 10px height to the first such element:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('height')[0].style.height = '10px';
```

Comment: I tried all the ways in javascript not working  in typescript. please suggest me any way to get and update height in typescript.

Comment: var result = document.getElementsByClassName('height')[0];
var wrappedResult = angular.element(result);
wrappedResult.css('height', '100px');

Answer (score 1):

First, the code you are after:

```
const cnElems = document.getElementsByClassName("cn");

for (let i = 0; i < cnElems.length; i++) {
    const e = cnElems[i];
    if (e instanceof HTMLElement) {
        e.style.height = "10px";
    }
}
```

Then, an explanation... There are two main obstacles here:

- `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection<Element>`
  for older targets and browsers this collection needs to be enumerated with an old-school `for` loop. For newer targets (>= ES6) and browsers, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22754453/2894770).
- the elements of the collection are of type `Element` but `style` is defined on `HTMLElement`. Luckily TS automatically narrows a type in the scope of a [type guard](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#424-type-guards).