# Replace alt text attribute of images getting text in paragraph

Tags: javascript, attributes, alt

I'm trying to get text in paragraph ".name" and put into all alt attribute in an image gallery. How can i get this text and put into attribute changing the current text. For example: in .box-product one the image of product 0001 should get alt text from this paragraph Box 0001

and another blocks the same respectly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("box-product").length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("name")[i].setAttribute(
      "alt", document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].src);
  }
});
```

```css
.box-product {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px gray solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Product Gallery -->
<div class="gallery-products">
  <!-- Product 0001 -->
  <div class="box-product">
    <a id="product" href="#" class="details">
      <p class="image">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/3_D-Box.jpg" height="100" alt="Replace this alt" id="" />
      </p>
    </a>
    <p class="name">Box 0002</p>
  </div>
  <!-- Product 0002 -->
  <div class="box-product">
    <a id="product" href="#" class="details">
      <p class="image">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/3_D-Box.jpg" height="100" alt="Replace this alt" id="" />
      </p>
    </a>
    <p class="name">Box 0002</p>
  </div>
  <!-- Product 0003 -->
  <div class="box-product">
    <a id="product" href="#" class="details">
      <p class="image">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/3_D-Box.jpg" height="100" alt="Replace this alt" id="" />
      </p>
    </a>
    <p class="name">Box 0003</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. Please add jQuery. 2. Please fix typo. There is no such thing as setElementByTagname 3. Use jQuery for all access or don't use jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you meant this?

I use jQuery for all the access - you had typos in your DOM access

```js
$(function() {
  $(".box-product").each(function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("alt",$(this).find("p.name").text());
  });
});
```

```css
.box-product {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px gray solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Product Gallery -->
<div class="gallery-products">
  <!-- Product 0001 -->
  <div class="box-product">
    <a id="product" href="#" class="details">
      <p class="image">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/3_D-Box.jpg" height="100" alt="Replace this alt" id="" />
      </p>
    </a>
    <p class="name">Box 0002</p>
  </div>
  <!-- Product 0002 -->
  <div class="box-product">
    <a id="product" href="#" class="details">
      <p class="image">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/3_D-Box.jpg" height="100" alt="Replace this alt" id="" />
      </p>
    </a>
    <p class="name">Box 0002</p>
  </div>
  <!-- Product 0003 -->
  <div class="box-product">
    <a id="product" href="#" class="details">
      <p class="image">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/3_D-Box.jpg" height="100" alt="Replace this alt" id="" />
      </p>
    </a>
    <p class="name">Box 0003</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery,

```
$('.box-product').each(function() {
    $(this).children('img').attr('alt', $(this).children('.name').text());
});
```

Basically, `$('.box-product')` gets all of the boxes. Then you need to loop through each, getting the text from it's child `.name` and assigning it to the `alt` attribute of it's child `img`.

Without jQuery, you can use the `querySelectorAll` and `querySelector` functions to easily the same.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.box-product').forEach(function() {
    this.querySelector('img').alt = this.querySelector('.name').innerText;
});
```

And without those functions (for older browsers):

```
var products = document.getElementsByClassName('box-product');
for(i in products) {
    var product = products[i];
    product.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].setAttribute('alt', product.getElementsByClassName('name')[0].innerText);
}
```

Comment: I think your edit is wrong however. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/foreach-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements - older browsers do not support foreach and no browsers support foreach on an html collection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/foreach-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements

Comment: @mplungjan Indeed. Thanks for pointing that out, tried to convert too fast. I've updated it to something that should work.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why this is being downvoted. I gave three perfectly valid solutions to answer the question.

Comment: I agree. There is no longer any reason (not that there was any to begin with, but the foreach could have triggered it)