# Changing color of a grid box with javascript

Tags: javascript, bind

I am trying to learn javascript and i made a grid with some boxes in it and i'm trying to change the color of the grid box when i click on it. I know i can use jquery i did it and worked but i want to do this with javascript only so this is my code so far:

```
var grid = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

function changeColor(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.style.background = 'black';
  });
};

grid.forEach(function(el) {
  changeColor(el);
});
```

I feel like this needs 'bind' method and i dont know how bind works yet so is it possible to make it work without bind? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to declare a separate function. You can just catch all the elements with `box` class, then iterate over them with `forEach()` function and bind a `click` event to every element.

**Note**: grid variable isn't an array. It's an array-like object. To be able to use `forEach()` function over it, you have to use `Array#from` to change it into an array.

```js
var grid = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

Array.from(grid).forEach(v => v.addEventListener('click', function() {
  v.style.background = 'black';
}));
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: lightgreen;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The line `grid.forEach` is invalid. If you open your browser's developer console, you should see it raises a TypeError. If you run `console.log(grid)`, you'll see that `grid` is an `HTMLCollection`, and that [can't be iterated over using forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/foreach-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements).

You can convert `grid` to an Array first with `Array.from(grid)`, or use `[].forEach.call(grid, changeColor)`