# Why can’t I itertate through children of an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, loops

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), a `HTMLCollection`, which the `children` property of an Element happen to be, is an “array-like object”. OK, so let’s try to iterate through it:

```js
for(var par in document.getElementById("Container").children)
  document.getElementById("Results").innerHTML +=
    par.id+"<br>"
```

```html
<div id="Container">
  <p id="Par1"></p>
  <p id="Par2"></p>
</div>

<p id="Results"></p>
```

First of all, why am I shown 5 lines instead of 2, one per each paragraph? Then, why do I get `undefined`s instead of `Par1` and `Par2`?

Oddly enough, looping through its indexes works as expected:

```js
var cont = document.getElementById("Container");
for(var i = 0; i < cont.children.length; i++)
  document.getElementById("Results").innerHTML +=
    cont.children[i].id+"<br>";
```

```html
<div id="Container">
  <p id="Par1"></p>
  <p id="Par2"></p>
</div>

<p id="Results"></p>
```

What do I fail to understand?

Comment: When you use `for (var x in array)`, `x` gets the indexes of the array elements, not the values.

Comment: Try putting `console.log(par)` in your loop and you'll see the problem.

Comment: And then you'll also see that this is an example of why you shouldn't iterate over arrays (or array-like objects) with `for..in`: because you don't just get the array element indices, you get other object property names too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/foreach-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements

Comment: @gaazkam—for the reason nnnnnn said, you are getting all enumerable properties of the collection, including inherited ones if there are any, not just the numeric ones (aka indexes).

Comment: Some browsers have implemented *forEach* for NodeLists which will make life easier. There is also [*for..of*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), but support is lacking there too. :-(

Comment: MDN `for..in` do suggest you should using `for` instead to iterate Array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement