# Polymer using getElementsby# method on inner-h-t-m-l

Tags: javascript, arrays, polymer

I'm trying to retrieve properties on various elements within a text that is loaded through inner-h-t-m-l but I fail to get just one specific element.

Here is my code:

```
<template>

<iron-ajax
      auto
      url="[[some/path/url.html]]"
      handle-as="text"
      last-response="{{inputText}}"></iron-ajax>

<div class="textcontent" inner-h-t-m-l="{{inputText}}"></div>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'text-page',

      ready: function() {
        var test = document.getElementsByClassName("author");
        console.log(test);
      }
    });
</script>
```

So I have two questions about this:

1. Is this the best way to load an html page into a Polymer element?
2. The output of the console.log is an array that looks like this:

> ```
> HTMLCollection[0]
> 0: span.author
> 1: span.author
> 2: span.author
> length: 3
> __proto__: HTMLCollection
> ```

This is correct, there are 3 elements with class-name "author". But when I do the same thing with `console.log(test[0])` in order to get just the first one, I get `"undefined"` as output. How do I get just the first one, and more importantly, the value of that `span`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, personally I think this is the best way to load HTML into a Polymer element unless you can use [HTML import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports) as normal way to do this.
2. With `getElementsByClassName` You are getting an `HTML collection` and you can't access directly the value of these elements.
   You can use different methods to get it as an array like [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from?v=example) or a [for...of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).
   Another solution could be getting them as an Array with the simple `this.querySelectorAll()`.

**Clarification [here (StackOverflow answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/for-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements#answer-22754453) and [here (Medium article)](https://hackernoon.com/htmlcollection-nodelist-and-array-of-objects-da42737181f9)**.

```js
const html = `<span class="author">test</span><span class="author">another</span>`
addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {

  Polymer({
    is: 'x-example',
    properties: {
      html: {
        type: String,
        value: html
      }
    },

    ready: function() {
      // 1° solution
      const test = this.getElementsByClassName('author');
      const first = Array.from(test)[0];
      console.log('First element innerText --->', first.innerText);

      // Or you can simply loop on the array
      Array.from(test).forEach(item => console.log(item.innerText));

      // 2° solution
      const test2 = this.querySelectorAll('.author');
      test2.forEach(item => console.log(item.innerText));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="x-example">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>

    <h1>polyfiddle</h1>
    <div inner-H-T-M-L="[[html]]">
    </div>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<x-example></x-example>
```

Comment: If I use `Array.from` it gives me back an empty array. If I do `console.log(test.length)` in the above code it also give me back `0`.

Comment: Here is a working example (though without `iron-ajax`), open up the console to see the results: https://jsfiddle.net/uq34vk2z/

Comment: Thank you! This worked without the iron-ajax but when I added the iron-ajax if failed. After some searching I found that it must be because the function is called before the text is loaded so `first` was `undefined`. So I added an `if (first !== undefined)` and then it worked just fine.

Comment: I spoke too soon. Looking a bit further I noticed that it did not get the information from the imported HTML file but from a child-element. When I removed that, it again gives first as undefined.

Comment: Yeah, the problem seems to be that you are not waiting for the element to be attached. You can use an observer for this. Here is a working example with the observer: http://jsfiddle.net/6t64j81d/. I'm emulating the `iron-ajax` with the `ready` callback of the Polymer lifecycle. I hope it helps!