# How to prevent js animation from happening again

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to make this animation where the side black rectangles "move aside" when I click on of the buttons. However when I click on the button second time, it behaves all weird and stuff, the rectangles on sides start to appear and disappear rapidly. I tried to prevent it by setting the onlick attribute of the buttons to empty after the animation function finishes, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on how I can set it to that it runs only once?
Thanks

```js
var W = document.body.clientWidth;

function move() {
  
    var left = document.getElementById("left");   
    var right = document.getElementById("right");
    var pos = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 1);

    function frame() {
        if (pos > W/3) {
            clearInterval(id);
            document.getElementsByClassName("NavLink").onclick = "";
        } else {
            pos++; 
            left.style.left = -3*pos + 'px'; 
            right.style.right = -3*pos + 'px'; 
        }
    }
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
nav h1,a{
  color: black;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  margin-top: 2vw;
  margin-bottom: 2vw;
}
nav h1{
  margin-bottom: 6vw;
}

aside{
  position: absolute;
  width: 33vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}
#left{
  left: 0;
}
#right{
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Paggo</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styllo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scriptto.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- ########################################################### -->
<body>
<div id="grid">
  
  <aside id="left"></aside>
  <aside id="right"></aside>

  <nav>
    <button onclick="move()" class="NavLink"> Link </button>
    <button onclick="move()" class="NavLink"> Link </button>
    <button onclick="move()" class="NavLink"> Link </button>
    <button onclick="move()" class="NavLink"> Link </button>
  </nav>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). You cannot set `onclick` directly on this collection. Instead, you should [loop over each element in the collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22754315/578288).

This only solves the problem of being able to run the animation again after it has finished. I did not fix the bug of being able to start the animation again after it has already started.

```js
var W = document.body.clientWidth;

function move() {
  
    var left = document.getElementById("left");   
    var right = document.getElementById("right");
    var pos = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 1);

    function frame() {
        if (pos > W/3) {
            clearInterval(id);
            var navLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("NavLink");
            for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
              var navLink = navLinks[i];
              navLink.onclick = "";
            }
            
        } else {
            pos++; 
            left.style.left = -3*pos + 'px'; 
            right.style.right = -3*pos + 'px'; 
        }
    }
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
nav h1,a{
  color: black;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  margin-top: 2vw;
  margin-bottom: 2vw;
}
nav h1{
  margin-bottom: 6vw;
}

aside{
  position: absolute;
  width: 33vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}
#left{
  left: 0;
}
#right{
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Paggo</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styllo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scriptto.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- ########################################################### -->
<body>
<div id="grid">
  
  <aside id="left"></aside>
  <aside id="right"></aside>

  <nav>
    <button onclick="move()" class="NavLink"> Link </button>
    <button onclick="move()" class="NavLink"> Link </button>
    <button onclick="move()" class="NavLink"> Link </button>
    <button onclick="move()" class="NavLink"> Link </button>
  </nav>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```