# JS change all 'p' color

Tags: javascript

i want to change color all 'p' elements, i tried do it with this code but it not works.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p').forEach(element => {
 element.style.color = 'white'
});
```

Is there a right way(without using JQuery)?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('p').style.color = 'white'` try that way.

Comment: ^ this returns a `NodeList`, not an `HTMLCollection`, which **can** be iterated over. You can't just set the `style.color` for the `NodeList`, though!

Comment: Yeah, you're right @chemicalcrux. My bad. But this code works `document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(e => e.style.color = "white")`

Comment: First, that is not jQuery, second, how is that code piece not working? ... Provide a code snippet reproducing the issue described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the vanilla JavaScript ES2015 (ES6) code.

```
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(e => e.style.color = "white");
```

**UPDATE:**

I forgot to mention that this is applying white color of the element in the **DOM** which is not so efficient, so you can also do this in another way.

CSS:

```
.white {
  color: #fff;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
// If you have just one class for the element
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(e => e.className = 'white');

// If you are appending the class of `white`
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(e => e.className += ' white');
```

Comment: @H.Denision But this is not compatible in older browsers. Still, suggest adding Array.from()

Comment: @SandeepRanjan Your answer is written in ES6 code and ES6 is not compatible with older browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same like this

```
var list= document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].style.color = "white";
}
```

As `document.getElementsByTagName` returns *HTMLCollection* type object you have to iterate using above method as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22754453/4041534) answer

Answer (score 1):

You can't iterate over the `HTMLCollection` returned by `getElementsByTagName`. Converting it to an `Array` will work, though. Use `Array.from()` to do this:

`Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('p')).forEach(element => {
 element.style.color = 'white'
});`

Comment: you can also just use a for ... of loop


    for(let element of document.getElementsByTagName('p')) {
     element.style.color = 'yellow'
    }

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do here is to make a simple loop.

```
let el = document.getElementsByTagName('p')
let i

for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    el[i].style.color = 'white'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')
```

Return `HTMLCollection(6) [p, p, p, p, p, p.left]` This is a HTML Collection.
So if you check

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p') instanceof Array
```

It returns `false`.

As HTML Collections are not array's so you cannot perform `.forEach()`.

So you must convert it into an array by using `Array.from()`.

> The `Array.from()` method creates a new, shallow-copied Array instance
>   from an array-like or iterable object.

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('p')).forEach(element => {
 element.style.color = 'white'
});
```

So this is the solution for your problem.