# How do I select all p tags and make them visible when check box is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I want all the `<p>` elements to be displayed when the checkbox is checked and otherwise not displayed.

```js
function change(){
    var nav = document.getElementById("navbar");
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("checkbox");

    if(checkBox.checked == true){
        nav.style.width = "300px";
    } else{
        nav.style.width = "70px";
    }
}
```

```css
nav{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.3s;
    /* #63. change 2nd to -10px from -6px */
    box-shadow: rgba(136, 165, 191, 0.26) 4px 2px 10px 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) -4px -2px 16px 0px;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    color:black;
}

nav p{
    display: none;
}

nav input{
    margin: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav input:checked + nav p{
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
        <input onclick="change()" type="checkbox" name="" id="checkbox">
        
        <ul>
            <a href="#">
                <li>
                    <p>Home</p>
                </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <li>
            
                    <p>Summer</p>
                </li>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you need to add to CSS and it should work.

```
nav input:checked + ul p {
  display: block;
}
```

Result you can see in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexNis/8wodkpa1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` to select each p element and then use `element.style.display` to change whether or not it is visible.

```
let on = checkbox.checked;
document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(e => {
  e.style.display = on ? "block" : "none";
});
```

Note that you can use any selector inside `document.querySelectorAll()`, including classes, attributes, IDs, etc.

Snippet:

```js
function change(){
    var nav = document.getElementById("navbar");
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("checkbox");

    if(checkBox.checked == true){
        nav.style.width = "300px";
    } else{
        nav.style.width = "70px";
    }

    let on = checkbox.checked;
    document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(e => {
      e.style.display = on ? "block" : "none";
    });
}
```

```css
nav{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.3s;
    /* #63. change 2nd to -10px from -6px */
    box-shadow: rgba(136, 165, 191, 0.26) 4px 2px 10px 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) -4px -2px 16px 0px;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    color:black;
}

nav p{
    display: none;
}

nav input{
    margin: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav input:checked + nav p{
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
        <input onclick="change()" type="checkbox" name="" id="checkbox">
        
        <ul>
            <a href="#">
                <li>
                    <p>Home</p>
                </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <li>
            
                    <p>Summer</p>
                </li>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [JS change all 'p' color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51005059/js-change-all-p-color):

Make all paragraphs `display: none` and then with JS in your function change(): `document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(e => e.style.display = 'block');`

```js
function change(){
    var nav = document.getElementById("navbar");
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("checkbox");

    if(checkBox.checked == true){
        nav.style.width = "300px";
        document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(e => e.style.display = 'block');
    } else{
        nav.style.width = "70px";
        document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(e => e.style.display = 'none');
    }
}
```

```css
nav{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.3s;
    /* #63. change 2nd to -10px from -6px */
    box-shadow: rgba(136, 165, 191, 0.26) 4px 2px 10px 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) -4px -2px 16px 0px;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    color:black;
}

nav p{
    display: none;
}

nav input{
    margin: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav input:checked + nav p{
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
        <input onclick="change()" type="checkbox" name="" id="checkbox">
        
        <ul>
            <a href="#">
                <li>
                    <p>Home</p>
                </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <li>
            
                    <p>Summer</p>
                </li>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it as simple as possible, you can dynamically change the visibility property of the element. I would also personally not target the p>tags in this case but rather the whole list item, so that you don't render uneccessary DOM elements (i.e. there is no point in having an a tag and a list item if nothing will be displayed in it). So I would add an identifier to the a tag and toggle the visibility prop of the element:

Add a class to each list item:

```
<nav id="navbar">
    <input onclick="change()" type="checkbox" name="" id="checkbox">
    
    <ul>
        <a class="navbar-item" href="#">
            <li>
                <p>Home</p>
            </li>
        </a>
        <a class="navbar-item" href="#">
            <li>
        
                <p>Summer</p>
            </li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Modify the onChange function to toggle the visibility:

```
function change(){
  var nav = document.getElementById("navbar");
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("checkbox");

  var navbarItems = document.getElementByClassname("navbar-item");

  if(checkBox.checked == true){
    nav.style.width = "300px";
    navbarItems.style.visibility="visible";
  } else {
    nav.style.width = "70px";
    navbarItems.style.visibility="hidden"; 
  }
}
```

Remove this from the css:

```
nav p{
  display: none;
}
```

Add this to the css:

```
.navbar-item {
  visibility: 'hidden'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to move away from `inline` event handlers using `onclick` and use an external event listener - keep the HTML as clean as possible. Use `querySelector` to select specific nodes and `querySelectorAll` to select a [nodelist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) - which can be converted to an array if required quite easily using `Array.from(nodelist)` - which then gives access to various array methods. In this case though that is not required - `forEach` works on a nodelist so processing each `p` element becomes simple.

```js
document.querySelector('nav#navbar input[type="checkbox"]').addEventListener('click',function(e){
  let col=this.parentNode.querySelectorAll('p');
      col.forEach(p=>p.style.display=this.checked ? 'block' : 'none')
  this.parentNode.style.width=this.checked ? '300px' : '70px';
})
```

```css
nav{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.3s;
    /* #63. change 2nd to -10px from -6px */
    box-shadow: rgba(136, 165, 191, 0.26) 4px 2px 10px 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) -4px -2px 16px 0px;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    color:black;
}

nav p{
    display: none;
}

nav input{
    margin: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav input:checked + nav p{
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
    <input type="checkbox" value=1 />
    <ul>
        <a href="#">
            <li>
                <p>Home</p>
            </li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <li>
                <p>Summer</p>
            </li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```