# Aframe.js: Can someone give me an example to add model loaded event?

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

**Description:**

Hello, I was hoping to create a loading screen in Aframe. I found the page below, it's about object loading but I couldn't figure out how to use it...

https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/asset-management-system.html#lt-a-asset-item-gt

```
<a-asset-item class="model" id="back" src="./models/back.obj"></a-asset-item>
<img id="backTex" src="./textures/back.png">

<a-asset-item class="model" id="front" src="./models/front.obj"></a-asset-item>
<img id="frontTex" src="./textures/front.png">
```

-

```
var models = document.getElementsByClassName("model");

/*trial 1*/
for(var i in models){
    models[i].addEventListener("loaded",()=>{console.log("loaded!")});//CAN'T FIND addEventListener
}

function OnLoaded(){
console.log("loaded!");
}

/*trial 2*/
for(var i in models){
    models[i].loaded  = OnLoaded;
}
```

On the html file, I have some `<a-asset-item class="model" id="mainModel" src="./models/mainModel.obj"></a-assets-item>` ,

I stored all of models that has `model` class. And I tried to add event listener to its child but it said `"addEventListenr is not a function"` I don't think there is addEventListener to this element.

So I console.logeed the children and I saw some events like variables in it (onclick, onmousedown etc..)
and added the variable, "loaded" and "model-loaded" to the children. This time no error but nothing happened.

I also tried with the event name "model-loaded" but also didn't work...
https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/obj-model.js#L51

Can someone give me some examples of how to use `loaded` event for`<a-assets-item>`?
Thanks in advance.

- A-Frame Version: 0.7.1
- Reproducible Code Snippet or URL:

---

**Update**

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.models[i].length; i++){
    this.models[i].addEventListener("model-loaded", ()=>{console.log("Hello!");})
    this.models[i].addEventListener("loaded", ()=>{console.log("Hello!");})
}
```

I changed the "for/in" to regular for loop. Now it doesn't cause any error but doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection` . Iterating through it using `for .. in` gets unexpected results ( such as the for loop trying to add an event listener to a `item()` function, which is a part of the collection.

---

If you use a typical for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < models.length; ++i) {
  models[i].addEventListener(....)
}
```

It should be working.

---

Actually what you were doing should be working - since the models got the event listeners attached, with an error only when the loop reached the `item()` function.

Furthermore, [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22754453/2425787) has more info about iterating through a `HTMLCollection`

---

As for the event names - the `<a-asset-item>` as a `a-node` emits the `loaded` event
, but a `<a-obj-model>` or `<a-entity obj-model="">` will emit the `model-loaded` event.

Comment: Hello Piotr, Thank you for your answer. I tried with regular for loop and it didn't cause any error now! Thank you so much for the advice. Now it doesn't cause any error but nothing happens now...

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < this.models[i].length; i++){
   this.models[i].addEventListener("model-loaded", ()=>{console.log("Hello!");})
   this.models[i].addEventListener("loaded", ()=>{console.log("Hello!");})
  }

Comment: I added the event listener to the objects. But still nothing happens... Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?? Thanks

Comment: @TatsumaNakano `model-loaded` [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-assetsloaded?path=index.html:20:111)

Answer (score 0):

`<a-asset-item>`s are not models. They are just for network preloading.

Use `<a-obj-model>` and put your model class on those.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thank you for your answer!
Could you please give me an example of usage if you have any chance? I used the `<a-obj-model>` but still doesn't do anything...

Comment: @ngoKevin shouldn't any `<a-asset-item>` fire the `loaded` item once the resource is loaded by the `Three fileLoader` ?

Comment: `<a-entity id="foo" obj-model>`, `document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('model-loaded', () => {})`

Comment: Your code has lots of typos too...`addEventListenr`, `<a-assets-item>`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change your event listener to the `object3dset` event. So the code would be something like:

`models[i].addEventListener('object3dset', e => this.doSomethingWithModel());`