# Typescript - How to iterate over a HTMLCollection

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript and I'm trying to iterate over a HTMLCollection got by `document.getElementsByClassName()`. My code is:

```
let tag_list = document.getElementsByClassName("...") as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLLinkElement>;
for (const tag of tag_list) {
    //do sth with tag.href
}
```

But it turns out that "TS2495: Type 'HTMLCollectionOf' is not an array type or a string type." So what is the best way I can do to prevent this error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLLinkElement>` is not an array, therefore, you cannot iterate it. So, you need to make it an array

```
for (const tag of Array.from(tag_list)) {
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that "Property 'from' does not exist on type 'ArrayConstructor.'"

Comment: It is, here's the ArrayConstructor

Comment: ```interface ArrayConstructor {
    from<T>(iterable: Iterable<T> | ArrayLike<T>): T[]; from<T, U>(iterable: Iterable<T> | ArrayLike<T>, mapfn: (v: T, k: number) => U, thisArg?: any): U[];
}```

Answer (score 1):

As shown by [this S.O. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53099727/1624376), it's compilation dependant.

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave"  : true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny"   : true,
    "target"          : "ES2021",
    "moduleResolution": "Node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

The following code compiles and runs:

```
const tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td') as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLTableCellElement>;
for( const td of tds ) {
  Utils.onClick( td, ( event: UIEvent ) => this.place( event, 1, 1 ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can smash Typescript into thinking anything is any type by converting it to `any` first and then to the type you want, like this:

```js
for (const child of dom.children as any as HTMLElement[]) {
  ....
}
```

Ugly but effective, this technique lets you "lie" to Typescript about a type. Since JavaScript will happily iterate over an HTMLElement's children, lying to Typescript like this lets JavaScript just do its thing.