# Why is my function and loop not able to access my global variable?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The NodeList I have been using as a variable in functions has been working, but it it not working in the latest one on which I am working.

It gives an error "card is not defined."  When I pass the variable into the function, it says it isn't iterable.

```
function matchCards() {
    if(hand[0] === hand[1]) {
        addPoint();
    } else if(hand[0] != hand[1]) {
        flipBack();
    }
}
function flipBack (cards) {
    for(card of cards) {
        if(card.firstElementChild.src != "img/cardback.jpeg") {
            for(const id of ids) {
                document.querySelector(`[alt="${id}"]`).src = "img/cardback.jpeg";
                console.log(document.querySelector(`[alt="${id}"]`).src);
                hand = [];
                changePlayer();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the global variable I'm trying to use:

```
const cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
```

This is a link to the whole project: https://codepen.io/ThomasBergman1987/pen/LqrJQM

Comment: `cards` can not be both a global variable and a function parameter at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are hiding the value of your global constant by defining a parameter in the function with the same name:

```
const cards = ...;

function flipBack (cards) {
    // The following print statement will print the 
    // value of the parameter, not the global constant
    console.log(cards); 
}
```

Furthermore, when you call `flipBack` in your other function, you call it without passing any parameters, which causes the value of the parameter `cards` to be undefined.

You can fix the issue by simply removing `cards` from your function's parameter list:

```
function flipBack () {
    // ...
}
```

As for why the code is saying `cards` is not iterable, `cards` is going to be an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). While most modern browsers will support iterating on that kind of object with `for/in`, this functionality is not guaranteed, and [you shouldn't be doing that anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22754453/1255873). The safer approach is to use a normal for loop:

```
function flipBack () {
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        var card = cards[i];
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Thomas Run `console.log(cards);` inside the function and see what it actually is.

Comment: It says it is undefined.

Comment: @Thomas Do you still have `cards` as a parameter?

Comment: I still have `cards` as a parameter.  Yes.

Comment: I took the time to read the resources you provided and wrote down the solutions to make sure I had the details right.  I appreciated their greater detail on this issue too.  But I still must be missing something.

Comment: @Thomas The solution is the lone sentence right smack in the middle of my answer: **You can fix the issue by simply removing `cards` from your function's parameter list**

Comment: I think I have a complete understanding of the problem now.  I had removed it at one point, but that didn’t solve it immediately.  So I put it back and then tried the regular `for` loop solution, but I hadn’t tried the new `for` loop without the parameter.  Thanks for your time and effort, and the solution!  I think I can apply the solution in other areas as well!

Comment: @Thomas see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for an explanation of what to do when someone answers. In particular, see the part about marking an answer as accepted if it you find it provides a solution to your question

Answer (score 0):

You're sending cards as an argument to `flipBack()` function, it's either you remove it or send cards again when you call the function `flipBack(cards)`

```
function matchCards() {
    if(hand[0] === hand[1]) {
        addPoint();
    } else if(hand[0] != hand[1]) {
        flipBack();
    }
}
function flipBack () {
    for(card of cards) {
        if(card.firstElementChild.src != "img/cardback.jpeg") {
            for(const id of ids) {
                document.querySelector(`[alt="${id}"]`).src = "img/cardback.jpeg";
                console.log(document.querySelector(`[alt="${id}"]`).src);
                hand = [];
                changePlayer();
            }
        }
    }
}
```