# alternative of jquery's $.each in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I want to loop through each element by its class for setting new value in the src attribute. below is the jquery code, how can i rewrite in typescript in angular

```
$(".image").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("src","http://xxx/xxx.png");
});
```

Comment: What's the issue you are having?

Comment: You wouldn't. Use property binding to bind to the `src` element of each image directly.

Comment: You generally don't modify the DOM in Angular. You modify the model which is the single point of truth, and the view is modified accordingly. You need to learn how to do things the Angular way, and not the jQuery way.

Comment: In my case iam dynamically appending html to template. After that  i want to change the src of element .Is there any way to do it in typescript @JBNizet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may help you:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("image")).forEach(function(item) {
    var image_link=item.getAttribute('href');
    item.setAttribute('src',"path");
});
```

Please check this for details: [For loop for HTMLCollection elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/for-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements/22754453#22754453)

Comment: Thanks that what iam looking for @Anoop Sanker

Answer (score 1):

Try to use opposite approach - store collection inside component and iterate inside view:

**component.ts**

```
public urls = ['url1', 'url2'];
```

**component.html**

```
<img *ngFor="let url of urls" [src]="url">
```

If you change something in your `urls` now it will affect the view.

Comment: In my case i am dynamically appending html to template. After that  i want to change the src of element .Is there any way to do it in typescript @Patryk Uszyński

Comment: @Vishnudas you can start with empty `urls` array. When you dynamically push new item it will be rendered.