# JS - How can I display a value in two different places from one javascript output?

Tags: javascript, html

JS sends current time (hh:mm) and updates HTML page using .innerHTML.

I want to display time at two locations in same page so I duplicated the html

```
    <div class="time"></div>
    <div class="time"></div>
```

now using [0] and [1], I can call the same class twice.

```
    document.getElementsByClassName("time")[0].innerHTML = hour+":"+minute+":"+second;
    document.getElementsByClassName("time")[1].innerHTML = hour+":"+minute+":"+second;
```

Is there anyway I can call both by single line. Did a quick search but couln't find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a `Array.from` and `forEach` ( ES6 )

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("time")).forEach(function(item) {
   item.innerHTML = hour+":"+minute+":"+second;
});
```

If you must manipulate DOM frequently maybe i suggest you to use [Jquery](https://jquery.com/) for an easier way to perform this kind of thing

Aswell if you want to learn more about loop for HTML collection , [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/for-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements) is a must seen

Answer (score 1):

Using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
// Not your time format, but still used to visualize
const date = new Date();

document.querySelectorAll('.time').forEach(elem => elem.innerText = date);
```

```html
<div class="time"></div>
<div class="time"></div>
```

Using [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName):

```js
// Again to visualize
const date = new Date();

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('time')).forEach(elem => elem.innerText = date);
```

```html
<div class="time"></div>
<div class="time"></div>
```

This works too ([Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)):

```js
const date = new Date();

[...document.getElementsByClassName('time')].forEach(elem => elem.innerText = date);
```

```html
<div class="time"></div>
<div class="time"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the index, pass as second parameter:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".time").forEach((el,i)=>el.innerHTML="element " + i)//hour+":"+minute+":"+second;)
```

```html
<div class="time"></div>
 <div class="time"></div>
```