# How to return values from html with same class in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, dom

I made a select tag in html and gave every option different values like this

`<option class="op" value="3"></option>
<option class="op" value="4"></option>
<option class="op" value="5"></option>`
I am trying to put this values in an array using js.

First I call the class and store in `var = values` then using the for loop I tried to put the values in an array but I get this error (i.value is not iterable)

```
var values = [...document.getElementsByClassName('op')];

for (i = 0; i< values.length; i++) {
    var originalValues = [...i.value];
    console.log(originalValues)
}
```

expected output: `originalValues = [1,2,3,...]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For loop for HTMLCollection elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/for-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you received is exactly correct. The HTMLCollection that is returned by `getElementsByClassName` is not iterable, so you can't use the spread syntax (`...`) on it. If you want to iterate over it, you will need to use the `for...of` loop, or a standard `for` loop on it, like so:

```
let values = [];
for (let node of document.getElementsByClassName('op')) {
  values.push(node.value);
}
```

or

```
let nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('op');
let values = [];
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  let node = nodes[i];
  values.push(node.value);
}
```

Comment: your code is unclear...At your first code what is line of code...should this line return the values?........................let values = node.value

Comment: @MarcoMaher You can do whatever you want with the node.value. You can log it, you can put it into an array - doesn't matter.

Comment: I couldn't get it at first but your code works perfectly thanks for the help!

Comment: @MarcoMaher Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

#### One line, no jQuery!

```
const values = [...document.getElementsByClassName('op')].map(op => op.value)
```

Basically it makes a new (real) array from the HTMLCollection, making the .map() method available that performs a specific operation on each item and returns a new array.

By the way the error comes from `i.value` in your loop. `i` is a number and does not have a `.value` property, so `i.value` is `undefined` hence is not iterable and can't be used with spread syntax.

Maybe this is what to wanted to do:

```
const htmlCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('op');
const originalValues = []

for (let i = 0; i < htmlCollection.length; i++) {
    originalValues[i] = htmlCollection[i].value;
    console.log(originalValues)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('op')
for (const input of inputs) {
    console.log(input.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery makes this pretty simple. Grab the select tag by it's class, `.op`, then grab all of it's children options with the `> option` and just loop over them.

```
var values = []
$('.op > option').each(function(index, option){
    values.push($(option).text())
})
console.log(values)
```

Quickest way to get started with jquery is to add this right after your body tag in your html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for help your answer worked. but look at the answer of barak avraham it is more simple and also worked...why would I use jquery over simple js

Answer (score 0):

Add the id in Select condition just like that;

```
<select name="opps" id="opps">
    <option class="op" value="3"></option>
    <option class="op" value="4"></option>
    <option class="op" value="5"></option>
</select>

var assignedId = new Array();
$("#opps option").each(function()
{
    assignedId.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(assignedId);
```