# Trouble understanding DOM API

Tags: javascript, html, css

The background color is getting applied to only c1 class and not c2 even though the code is same.
When i inspect it I am getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined

for the first class itself. I can’t find anything wrong with the code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
     table,th,td{
         border: 1px solid black;
         border-collapse: collapse;
         

     }

     
    </style>
    <table style="width:75%" >
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class='c1'>
          <td>Jill</td>
          <td>Smith</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='c2'>
          <td>Eve</td>
          <td>Jackson</td>
          <td>94</td>
        </tr>
          <tr class='c1'>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>80</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class='c2'>
            <td>Greg</td>
            <td>House</td>
            <td>50</td>
          </tr>
    
      </table>
      <script>
        var c1=document.getElementsByClassName('c1');
        console.log(c1)
        for(i in c1)
        {
            c1[i].style.backgroundColor='aqua';
        }
        var c2=document.getElementsByClassName('c2');
        for(var j in c2)
        {
          c2[j].style.backgroundColor='coral';
        }
      </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `for ... in` to loop through an array. See solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/for-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements).

Comment: @TiiJ7 so in short the variable c1 is not per say an array but a different type called HTMLCollection?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` does return a `HTMLCollection` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) for details), which is why I linked to that post. `HTMLCollection` is "array-like" (acts like an array, but is not one). But the advice is the same for arrays and array-like objects. Some more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-for-array-iteration-a-bad-idea).

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues:

1. The <STYLE> tag should be in the <HEAD> section.
2. The JavaScript code that attempts to set the background color is *best* run after you are sure the DOM has been initialized. It will now be invoked on the `onload` event.
3. The proper way to step through the collection of elements is to use: for elem **of** array.

```js
window.onload = function() {
        var c1=document.getElementsByClassName('c1');
        //console.log(c1)
        for(let elem of c1)
        {
            elem.style.backgroundColor='aqua';
        }
        var c2=document.getElementsByClassName('c2');
        //console.log(c2);
        for(let elem of c2)
        {
          elem.style.backgroundColor='coral';
        }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
     table,th,td{
         border: 1px solid black;
         border-collapse: collapse;
         

     }    
    </style> 
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <table style="width:75%" >
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class='c1'>
          <td>Jill</td>
          <td>Smith</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='c2'>
          <td>Eve</td>
          <td>Jackson</td>
          <td>94</td>
        </tr>
          <tr class='c1'>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>80</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class='c2'>
            <td>Greg</td>
            <td>House</td>
            <td>50</td>
          </tr>
    
      </table>

</body>
</html>
```