# Unable to Access HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, html, dom, jestjs, domparser

I have some code where I convert an HTML string to Document using DOM Parser. And then traverse the DOM to find an element depending on the class name.

**helper.js**

```
export function stringToHTML(htmlString) {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');
  return doc.body; 
}

export function getTextBoxInfo(htmlContent) {
  const textBox = {
    element: null,
    index: null
  };

  htmlContent.getElementsByClassName('document-content')[0].children.forEach((ele, index) => {
    if (ele.getAttribute('class').includes('freetext')) {
      textBox.element = freeTextElement;
      textBox.index = index;
    }
  });

  return textBox;
}
```

**helper.test.js**

```
describe('The getTextBoxInfo function', () => {
    it('returns an object with text box element and its position', () => {
        const htmlString = `<div class="document-content">
            <div class="content" id="bfb53c88"> Heading </div>
            <div class="freetext" contenteditable="true"> Content </div>
        </div>`;
        const htmlContent = helper.stringToHTML(htmlString);

        const textBox = helper.getTextBoxInfo(htmlContent);
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

It works fine with the source code. Document converted by DOM Parser is,

[Converted as Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mInqr.png)

But the output is different during unit testing(JEST),

[Converted differently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAPHz.png)

As a result the spec is failing with the below error,

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

at the line - htmlContent.getElementsByClassName('document-content')[0].children

and I am unable to write the tests.

Comment: You are calling `helper.stringToHTML(htmlString)` and then `helpers.stringToHTML(...)` on that result. Seems to be a mistake?

Comment: Thats a typo actually, was just trying different things. Issue is there even after thats updating it.

Comment: So, the result of `DOMParser` in tests does not have `.getElementByClassName`? Is that correct? What kind of error do you get, and at which line?

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky  Below is the error,

TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined at the line - htmlContent.getElementsByClassName('document-content')[0].children

Comment: Thanks! Could you add this info in the original question as well?

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky Ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of forEach, use normal for-loop or for-of loop as you are getting children as HTMLCollection

```
const children = htmlContent.getElementsByClassName('document-content')[0].children;
    for (let item of children) {
        console.log(item);
    }
```

Reference - [For loop for HTMLCollection elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/for-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements)

Comment: Thanks!. This works fine for this case but still, if i want to access something like item.innerText, it fails.