# how to loop through getElementById with incremental id

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I've got a webpage that got multiple ids like "action_1", "action_2", and so on..
I'dl like to loop through all these ids with a document.getElementById('action_'+i)

but as the pages got some variants, the i index is unknown . how should i loop for all the action_x ids?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `querySelector` instead of `getElementById`:

```js
document.querySelector('[id^="action_"]')
```

With the same selector and `querySelectorAll` (to loop over each actions):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="action_"]').forEach(function(action) {
  console.log(action);
});
```

The selector `[id^="action_"]` mean : each id attribute (whatever html tag), starting with "action_".

Learn more about attribute selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) for `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: This is more hacky. Since if you had an id somewhere in the app with "action_B" this would also be included in your result

Comment: Sure! But no any mentions about another thing than an index in the question.

Comment: thanks, yes there are only indexes in my case;
Could you explain a little more to me the expressions within this query? I don't understand it really well, and i don't know how to find the length of its answer

Comment: I've just edit my answer with some extra examples and docs.

Answer (score 1):

This approach isn't entirely correct.

You would instead put a class onto your actions alongside their ID's.

`<div class="actions"> </div>`

then you can use the `getElementsByClassName():`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

This will give you all your elements in an HTML collection which you then need to loop over.

this post will help you loop an  HTML collection: [For loop for HTMLCollection elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/for-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements)

Comment: I'm agree with that, but i'm not looping through MY Webpage.
It's someone else design that i cannot touch, i'm just injecting javascript in an already done webpage.

Comment: either approach is correct :). you can loop in javascript, definitly not in any other langugage