# Append each element to each div

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array with 2 elements, and I want to append each element to each div.

```js
let numbers = ['1', '2'];
var appendDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('append-div');

var addBtn = document.querySelector('.add-btn');
addBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Here goes the code
});
```

```html
<div class="append-div"></div>
<div class="append-div"></div>

<button class="add-btn">Add to Div</button>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to do a `foreach` loop to the array, and inside it, a `for` loop to the divs, but it didn't worked. @TannerDolby

Comment: Add that to your question and I'm happy to provide an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For loop for HTMLCollection elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/for-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate over the [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) `appendDiv` and string array `numbers`. Then assign each `.append-div` elements `textContent` with the values from your string array.

```js
let numbers = ['1', '2'];
var appendDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('append-div');

var addBtn = document.querySelector('.add-btn');
addBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < appendDiv.length; i++) {
      appendDiv[i].textContent = numbers[i];
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="append-div"></div>
<div class="append-div"></div>

<button class="add-btn">Add to Div</button>
```

Or use the more modern [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). But keep in mind, `getElementsByClassName` returns a live `HTMLCollection` which doesn't have access to Array methods like `forEach`. Therefore, you must convert the `HTMLCollection` to an `Array` using the spread operator and brackets like `[...HTMLCollection]`.

```js
let numbers = ['1', '2'];
var appendDiv = [...document.getElementsByClassName('append-div')];

var addBtn = document.querySelector('.add-btn');
addBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    appendDiv.forEach((element, index) => {
      element.textContent = numbers[index];
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="append-div"></div>
<div class="append-div"></div>

<button class="add-btn">Add to Div</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry about the errors. :)

Comment: Your welcome! See my second example for a more modern example with `forEach` usage. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the output you are looking for.

```
let numbers = ['1', '2'];
var appendDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.append-div');

var addBtn = document.querySelector('.add-btn');
addBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    appendDiv.forEach((item,i) =>{
        if(i < numbers.length){
            item.innerText = numbers[i]
        }
    })
  console.log(appendDiv,"appendDiv")
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :)

Comment: No worries :) . Why didn't you select my answer were there any errors?

Comment: Just because @TannerDelby explained more about the content, but it worked perfectly.

Comment: Ok no problem :)