# In javascript how I run a function on multiple divs with the same class to get different results

Tags: javascript, html, multiple-instances, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to run the same function on different divs with the same class. The thing is that I need the function to use offsetTop of each container and every div has a different value. The divs have the same class because I don't know how many divs are going to be present on each page of the site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

   <div class="container-div">
      <div class="element">Distance to top is </div>
   </div>
    
    <p>
        .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
    </p>

   <div class="container-div">
      <div class="element">Distance to top is </div>
   </div>

    <p>
        .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
    </p>

   <div class="container-div">
      <div class="element">Distance to top is </div>
   </div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Get distance</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
  var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container-div");
  
  container[0].innerHTML = "Distance to top for this Div is" container.offsetTop;
  container[1].innerHTML = "Distance to top for this Div is" container.offsetTop;
  container[2].innerHTML = "Distance to top for this Div is" container.offsetTop;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a for loop, to loop over all elements (no matter how many there are) and do some operation with them. If that's the case, you could take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/for-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand this is what you need, forEach loop trough all div's with class element. And you can get all div by class with document.querySelectorAll('.yourclass')

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div class="container-div">
    <div class="element">Distance to top is </div>
  </div>

  <p>
    .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
  </p>

  <div class="container-div">
    <div class="element">Distance to top is </div>
  </div>

  <p>
    .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
  </p>

  <div class="container-div">
    <div class="element">Distance to top is </div>
  </div>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Get distance</button>


  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      // Get all divs 

      const divElements = document.querySelectorAll('.element')
      // Loop trough all elements you selected
      divElements.forEach(element => {

        let distance = element.offsetTop;
        element.innerHTML = 'Distance to top is: ' + distance;

      });
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName("container-div")`
will return a collection of elements which have container-div class and you
can loop through them like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-div">
        <div class="element">Distance to top is </div>
    </div>
        
        <p>
            .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
        </p>

    <div class="container-div">
        <div class="element">Distance to top is </div>
    </div>

        <p>
            .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
        </p>

    <div class="container-div">
        <div class="element">Distance to top is </div>
    </div>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Get distance</button>


    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container-div");
            for(let i = 0; i<container.length;i++){
            container[i].innerHTML = "Distance to top is " + container[i].offsetTop;
            }
            
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```