# Node JS displaying value at index instead of indices

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-structures, ecmascript-6

Written this 2sums code to get efficent `O(N)` Time complexity algorithm for below problem

```
            Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
            Output: [0,1]
            Output: Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1].
```

unfortunately  saw value at array `nums` got displayed in the output ,whereas the need is  to get  the `indices` to be displayed in output

What change needs to be done below

```
            let hashTwoSum = (array, sum) => {
                let numsObj = {}
                let nums = []
               
                for(let i in array){
                    let addend = sum - array[i]
                   
                    if (addend in numsObj){

                        nums.push([addend, array[i]])

                    }
                    numsObj[array[i]] = i

                    
                }
                return nums
                
            }

            let array = [2,7,11,15]
            console.log(hashTwoSum(array,9))
```

Your help is appreciated

Regards,

Carolyn

Comment: instead of pushing the value at array[i] in nums, push i

Comment: Please don't ever iterate an array with `for(let i in array){...}`.  `for/in` is for iterating properties of an object, not elements of an array.  For details as to why, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754315/for-loop-for-htmlcollection-elements/22754453#22754453.  Use `for/of` to iterate items of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jriend00 said, do not use `for(... in ...)` loop for iterating arrays. But in your case, where you need indices, you need to use the good old `for` loop: `for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`. And when you save results, you need to push both *indices*: `nums.push([numsObj[addend], i])`.

Here's a complete example:

```
let hashTwoSum = (array, sum) => {
    let numsObj = {}
    let nums = []

    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        let addend = sum - array[i]

        if (addend in numsObj){
            nums.push([numsObj[addend], i])
        }
        numsObj[array[i]] = i
    }
    return nums
}

let array = [2,7,11,15,6]
console.log(hashTwoSum(array,17))
```

This will output:

```
[ [ 0, 3 ], [ 2, 4 ] ]
```

because 2 + 15 and 11 + 6 are both equal 17.