# Why is the element undefined when I iterate through all elements with a tag?

Tags: javascript, html

So whenever I run my code this

```
const sections = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
let colors = ["#ffc933", "#09ff00", "#00ccff", "#2b72ff", "#5436ff", "#dd54ff", "#5a0070", "05c9ff", "ff5405", "fa2d2d"];
for(ele in sections)
{
    console.log("Yes");
    ele.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)];
}
```

it always returns an error saying that the property style of ele can't be assigned to since it is undefined. This doesn't make any sense to me since it says for the elements in sections so all the ones that are there should be iterated through so nothing should be undefined.

Comment: You should use `for..of..` instead of `for..in..`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22754453/16688813) for more details.

Comment: You can use `document.querySelectorAll('section').forEach(ele => { ... })` instead.